# Stay away from these

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**Replace the question mark with the correct film director. Explain.**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the missing film director is:

> **David Fincher**, the director of [*Se7en*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114369/) (1995).

To find this answer, first identify all of the faces of other movie directors (using an online reverse image search tool, individually for each thumbnail):

> **Row 1:** Robert Altman, Todd Haynes, Lee Unkrich
>  **Row 2:** Wolfgang Reitherman, Eagle Egilsson, Dominic Sena
>  **Row 3:** Hrafn Gunnlaugsson, Peyton Reed, Eiji Tsuburaya
>  **Row 4:** Thom Eberhardt, Dickson Iroegbu, Nils Gaup
>  **Row 5:** Oldřich Lipský, Sayo Yamamoto, Victoria Larimore
>  **Row 6:** Yoshihiro Nishimura, Olof Thunberg, Tomu Uchida

Next...

> Create a 6x6 letter square from their **initials**:
>
> ```
> R  A  T  H  L  U
> W  R  E  E  D  S
> H  G  P  R  E  T
> T  E  D  I  N  G
> O  L  S  Y  V  L
> Y  N  O  T  T  U
> ```

And using the spiral-like image hint, realise that...

> ...we can find a series of words spelled out in a spiral formation, outwards from the centre:
>
>  [image: Seven Deadly Sins spelled out in a spiral]
>
>  These words are **[The Seven Deadly Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins)**: PRIDE, GREED, ENVY, SLOTH, WRATH, LUST and GLUTTONY, things one might be advised to 'stay away from', as per the title.

Armed with the hint that we are looking for the director of a movie from the 1990s with a connection to this theme this is in all likelihood:

> **David Fincher**, the director of [*Se7en*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114369/) (1995) - a movie about a serial killer carrying out their crimes according to a 'Seven Deadly Sins' pattern.

Comment: That's correct, exactly the director I was looking for. Well done!